# UPDATE variables y datos en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, sql, variables

Necesito guardar una ruta de una imagen en mi código, en caso de que el usuario al momento de modificar un producto no quiera modificar la imagen.

El problema actual es que lo manda en blanco y modifica la url de la imagen en la base de datos

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include '../head.php';
 $pro = $_GET['id_pro'];
 $sqli = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id_pro='$pro'";
 $eject = $con->query($sqli);
 while($fila = $eject->fetch_array()): 
////////////////////////////
if (empty($_POST['nombre_pro'])) {
  $nombre_pro=$fila['nombre_pro'];
}else{
 $nombre_pro = $_POST['nombre_pro'];
}
////////////////////////////////
if (empty($_POST['categoria'])) {
  $categoria=$fila['categoria'];
}else{
 $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
}
//////////////////// 
if (empty($_POST['descripcion'])) {
  $descripcion=$fila['descripcion'];
}else{
 $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
 }
//////////////////// 
if (empty($_POST['precio'])) {
  $precio=$fila['precio'];
}else{
 $precio = $_POST['precio'];
 }
//////////////////////
if (empty($_FILES['archivo'])){
  $nombreArchivo=$fila['image_pro'];
}else{
 $formatos = array('.jpg', '.png');
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $nombreTmpArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = substr($nombreArchivo, strrpos($nombreArchivo, '.'));
     if (in_array($ext, $formatos)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($nombreTmpArchivo, "images/$nombreArchivo")){
         print "<script>alert(Imagen subida con éxito);window.location='../artesa/formsArtesa/catalogo.php';</script>";
        }else{
         print "<script>alert(Error al subir imagen, comprueba el directorio del archivo);</script>";
        }
        }else{
          print "<script>alert(Formato de imagen no aceptado, intenta con JPG y PNG)</script>";
        }
 $imagen=$nombreTmpArchivo;
 }
 endwhile;
 $departamento = $_SESSION['departamento'];
 $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
 $enter = "UPDATE producto SET nombre_pro='$nombre_pro', image_pro='images/$nombreArchivo', descripcion='$descripcion', precio='$precio', departamento='       $departamento', categoria='$categoria' WHERE id_pro = '$pro'";
 $query = $con->query($enter);
 if ($query === true)
  header("location: ../formsArtesa/catalogo.php");
 else
  print "Error al agregar producto";
```

Comment: Usa dos *UPDATE*; uno cuando se incluya actualizar la imagen y otro donde no; y (como mencionas) cuando recibas en blanco lo tomas como si no hay imagen a actualizar.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas Muchas gracias :) ya pruebo!

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el manejador de BD que estás usando: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql ...? ¿Podrías igualmente indicar si usas PDO o MySQLi?

Comment: Phpmyadmin y MySQLi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error en la forma en la que detectas si se ha enviado o no el archivo:

```
if (empty($_FILES['archivo'])){
```

El contenido de `$_FILES['archivo']` cuando no se envía un archivo es:

```
array (
  'archivo' => 
  array (
    'name' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'tmp_name' => '',
    'error' => 4,
    'size' => 0,
  ),
)
```

El contenido de [`$_FILES['archivo']['error']` (ver documentación)](http://php.net/file-upload.errors) vale 4 (`UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`) para indicar que no hubo archivo y valdrá 2 (`UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`) si el tamaño máximo se ha excedido (`MAX_FILE_SIZE` de un campo oculto anterior), etc.

Por lo que tu `empty` siempre dará `false`, impidiendo que mantengas el valor anterior.

Deberías usar en su lugar:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['archivo']['error']) || $_FILES['archivo']['error'] != 0) {
```

Además, te recomiendo escapar todas las cadenas antes de enviarlas a una consulta SQL si no quieres usar consultas preparadas:

```
/* ¡¡IMPORTANTE SI NO USAS CONSULTAS PREPARADAS!! */
$pro = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id_pro']);
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id_pro='$pro'";
$eject = $con->query($sqli);
```

Y también:

```
/* ¡¡IMPORTANTE SI NO USAS CONSULTAS PREPARADAS!! */
$nombre_pro = $con->real_escape_string($nombre_pro);
$categoria = $con->real_escape_string($categoria);
$descripcion = $con->real_escape_string($descripcion);
$precio = $con->real_escape_string($precio);
$nombreArchivo = $con->real_escape_string($nombreArchivo);
$departamento = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['departamento']);
$id_user = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_user']);
$enter = "
  UPDATE
    producto
  SET
    nombre_pro='$nombre_pro',
    image_pro='images/$nombreArchivo',
    descripcion='$descripcion', precio='$precio',
    departamento='$departamento',
    categoria='$categoria'
  WHERE
   id_pro = '$pro'
";
$query = $con->query($enter);
```